# Creating a mailing list with Django & Sendgrid?

Tags: python, django, email, sendgrid

I would like to add a newsletter signup to my website which has a backend set up with Django. How should I go about handling email information when submitted to my site? Should I create a new model just for emails? Is there a way I can take emails inputted into my site and have them saved dynamically to my sendgrid account?

I would like to use sendgrid for all of my email campaigns and I would prefer having my data sent there instantly rather than saving in a model table and then manually inputting the contacts into my account.

Comment: You can store everything directly in SendGrid via the Marketing Campaigns API https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Just store everything on Sendgrid's servers. Sendgrid has API bindings for Python: `pip install sendgrid`.

1. Setup Celery or any other asynchronous task queue to process sign up requests in background. I recommend Celery, it's well supported to play nicely with Django.
2. Setup a task to handle signups asynchronously:

   ```
   # your_app/tasks.py:
   @celery.shared_task
   def newsletter_signup(email, newsletter):
       # use sendgrid API here
       pass


   # your_app/views.py
   def some_view(request):
       # do what you need, and send a sign up task whenever you want:
       newsletter_signup.delay(request.user.email, 'foobar')
       return HttpResponse('hello, world')
   ```

Actually, you can use their API directly (without Celery). But in this case request processing will take more time because of the extra time spent on communicating with the API.